# How to take the last value of a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem1{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //input
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word,letter;
    int counter=0, match,value;
    word=kb.next();
    word=word.toLowerCase();
    letter=kb.next();
    letter=letter.toLowerCase();
    //loop
    for (int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
      if (word.charAt(i)==letter.charAt(0)){
        counter++;
        match=i;
    System.out.print(match);
    }
    if (counter==0)
      System.out.print(-1);
  }
}
```

I must execute this program in Codio. This program will read a word and a letter, check whether the letter is in the word or not.

If yes, it will print the letter's index in the word; 
If the letter occurs more than once, it will print the last location. 
If the letter is not in the word, it will print -1.

When I ran it in Codio, there were 3 locations that had the letter: 2, 3 and 5. I only want to take 5.

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: Declare a variable outside of the loop. When you find a value that matches, update it. After the loop is done that local variable will hold the last value assigned to it.

Comment: how about `word.lastIndexOf(letter);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to output your last find, you need to move

```
System.out.print(match);
```

out of the loop.

But make sure that your counter is `>0` before you print `match`. Else you would get `0-1` as an output.

To do this either add another `if (counter > 0) { }` or move the print into the else block of your already existing `if (counter == 0)`

Comment: Hi, that worked for the check I asked! But another check had problem. This check was expected to print -1, but it printed 0-1. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: check for counter >0 before printing `match` you can do this as an `else` for the `if (counter==0)`

Comment: Thank you so much, all the checks passed! Please take this beautiful green check!

Comment: I am glad I could help! Have a great day.